# save a link to mysql database php

Tags: mysql, sql, hyperlink

I have a html form (for blogposts) and I want to save everything in a database table. It works fine but when I add a column for an image, which can also be uploaded in the same html form, then it is not saving anything.

Here's the code:

```
$imagepath = 'https://myurl.com/uploads/' . $_FILES['image']['name'];

  $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $query = $db->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO posts (author, title, text, date, image)
  VALUES(:author, :title, :text, NOW()), '$imagepath'");
  $query->execute(array("author" => $author, "title" => $title, "text" => $text));
  $db = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This..**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Upload'])) // upload button press
{

$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$folder = "uploads/";
$file_url="http://localhost/../../uploads/$file_name"; //file location

move_uploaded_file($file_temp,"Song_uploads/".$file_name);

$sql="INSERT INTO imagepost(file_NAME,file_URL,file_SIZE) VALUES(:file_name,:file_url,:file_size)";


    $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);


    $stmt->bindParam(':file_name',$file_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':file_url',$file_url);
    $stmt->bindParam(':file_size',$file_size);


    if($stmt->execute())
      {

    $message="<br/><h1> ---> "."[".$file_name."]"." File Has Been Uploaded !! </h1>";

      }
      else
      {
    $message="<br/> <h1> ---> "."[".$file_name."]"." File Not Be Uploaded !!  Please Try Again !! </h1>";
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: i dont know why you delete your reccent post ... but you can try this ..

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp ... You Can see This If You Want any More Thing in This. ...

Answer (score 0):

the closing parenthese is wrongly placed

```
  "INSERT INTO posts (author, title, text, date, image)
  VALUES(:author, :title, :text, NOW()), '$imagepath'");
```

should be

```
  "INSERT INTO posts (author, title, text, date, image)
  VALUES(:author, :title, :text, NOW(), '$imagepath' )");
```